# Is there a way to map an ObservableList of objects to an ObservableList of a single object.field?

Tags: javafx, binding

Given

```
public class Person {
    public final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
}
```

Is there any way to map an `ObservableList<Person>` to an `ObservableList<String>` without implementing a `ListChangeListener<Person>` to manually update the required list?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a library which does the trick:

https://github.com/tobiasdiez/EasyBind

It provides `EasyBind.map` with this exact functionality with a side note that the performed mapping function is executed on every get(int index), which decreases initial setup.

`EasyBind.mapBacked` provides an ObservableList in which the mapping function is already applied to every item, which may be preferable for intensive mapping functions.

Comment: Also see the [ReactFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX) library, which to some extent supersedes EasyBind. ReactFX has `LiveList.mapDynamic(...)` and `LiveList.map(...)` which have the same functionality as `EasyBind.map(...)` and `EasyBind.mapBacked(...)`, respectively. Some features of ReactFX were added in JavaFX 19, so you may see these becoming part of the base API in a future release.

Comment: A very nice addition and actually something I seem to have missed since we already use the reactFX library, thank you! Though sadly development and maintenance seems to have stopped on ReactFX. While tobiasdiez's EasyBind fork is actively being developed and maintained.